# Perl mongodb check if exists

Tags: perl, mongodb, find, exists

what is the fastest way in perl to check if the document in mongodb exists?

Is there any faster way than this?:

```
my $cursor = $cache->find( { "key" => $key->key } );

if ( $cursor->count ) {
return 1;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "if the *document* in mongodb exists". This query will not check if there is a document with the field `key` but rather if there is a document where the field `key` is equal to `$key->key`.

Comment: Yes thats true i want to check if there is field key equal to $key->key.

Comment: I corrected your question accordingly. Please note that you should be able to edit your question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `count` method is fine. To save a bit of code, you might use `find_one` instead:

```
return 1 if $cache->find_one( { "key" => $key->key } );
```

Both of these have about the same amount of network overhead, requiring at least two roundtrips to send the query and retrieve the results from the cursor.

You might save yourself a little processing time if you use a command instead. (Under the hood this just does a `find_one` against the `$cmd` collection, though.)

```
my $results = $cache->aggregate( [ { '$match' => { key => $cache->key } }, { '$limit' => 1 } ] );
return 1 if @$results;
```

But I doubt this level of network overhead will make much of a difference. I encourage you to benchmark it under realistic conditions and see what works best.